# Increasing mysql ram usage to decrease disk activity

Tags: mysql

I would like to know if the increasing the following parameters will improve the mysql performance.

```
| query_cache_size               | 16777216             |
| query_cache_limit              | 1048576              |
| table_open_cache               | 2000                 |
| table_open_cache_instances     | 16                   |
| thread_cache_size              | 8                    |
| host_cache_size                | 279                  |
```

Right now, the `innodb_buffer_pool_size` is 2G.

UPDATE:

The output of all variables is available at [pastebin](https://pastebin.com/zv1LtU84). I would like to decrease IO tasks as I have 32GB of memory and it is find to set 16 GB to mysql.

Comment: query cache generally decreases MySQL performance however has no effect on IO.  Thread/Host cache size and table_open_cache_instances has no effect on IO. Table open_cache if too small means files need to be closed/reopened so small. If you want help in tuning include `SHOW GLOBAL STATUS` output after at least a few hours and make this a broader question on reducing IO. Can you include your full configuration?

Comment: Please see the updated post.

Comment: quick things. a) this status is still < 1 hr. open_tables is 2k same same as table_open_cache so increase it. Created_tmp_disk_tables really 12k for the uptime is ~4 /second. For the number of select your handler_* values are really high so recommendation is to enable your slow query log, and fix the indexes on some queries. tmp disk tables is also an IO burden and correct indexing can help. innodb_buffer_pool < 20% use but that could just be low uptime.

Comment: There are `Table_open_cache_hits` and `Table_open_cache_misses` and `Table_open_cache_overflows`. Neither of them are equal to `open_tables` which is 2000.

Comment: right. so your `Table_open_cache_overflows` is still going up over time. Divide it by uptime and its ~2.5 per second. So the cache isn't big enough. `open_tables` is a level measurement the other `Table_open_cache*` measures are cumulative.

Comment: So, I will test with 6k instead of 2k. I didn't understand `Created_tmp_disk_tables`. Does that depend on uptime? I mean is that a dynamic value or I have to set an lower value (8k) in my.cnf?

Comment: That `GLOBAL STATUS` is not useful, for 2 reasons:  `SHOW VARIABLES` is needed and wait at least 24 hours before taking the `STATUS`.  (The 'Table_open_cache*` may not be meaningful due to the small `Uptime`.)

Comment: Do you have other processes running in the 32GB?  Can you afford to give 16GB to MySQL _without any swapping_?  If so, simply crank up `innodb_buffer_pool_size` by the most (not all) of the spare ram.  That will help more than fussing with the settings you are asking about.

Comment: @RickJames: I increased that to 8 GB and the mysql process is now taking 7.9 GB. I am monitoring to see if there are any slowdowns compared to the default value.

Answer (score 1):

Disk activity is either lots of stuff being read in or lots of stuff being written out because there isn't enough room in memory to hold it.

Increasing memory *might* reduce your disk activity, but it might *not* improve your overall performance.

Left to its own devices, your DBMS will not do lots of disk I/O for itself.  It only does so in response to *queries* that are sent to it.
You need to look at the workload (queries) that the server is running.  The chances are there are some "chunky" ones in there that are trawling through a lot of data.  Find them, tune them, get rid of them.  *That* will improve your server's overall performance.

Comment: Thanks I now that... However the queries are not straightforward. It is moodle which lots of reads and writes. Specially, when user want to save exam answers there are a lot of write queries. I want to know if the performance parameters are able to handle lots of read/write requests or default settings are pretty low end.

Comment: @mahmood - the slowlog will show you which query is the "worst".  Let's start by working on it.

Comment: @mahmood: One word answer: Testing. 
Whilst we can offer /generalisations/ about how a server might be set up, only you know the workload that /your/ server is facing or going to face.  Use your test system - you do have one, don't you? - to try thing out and see what works best for you.