# On reducing MYSQL disk activity

Tags: mysql, performance, cache

Following this [topic](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/270587), I want to reduce the disk activity for my Moodle database. Currently, the following variables are set

```
innodb_buffer_pool_size 8589934592
innodb_buffer_pool_chunk_size   134217728
innodb_ft_cache_size    8000000
key_buffer_size 16777216
key_cache_age_threshold 300
open_files_limit    5000
query_cache_limit   1048576
```

and

```
Open_tables 2000
Table_open_cache_hits   10705086
Table_open_cache_misses 137377
Table_open_cache_overflows  135369
Threads_cached  2
Threads_connected   65
Threads_created 29751
Threads_running 4
Uptime  96267
```

I have uploaded the full output of [SHOW GLOBAL STATUS](https://pastebin.com/dxSgWxvc) and [SHOW VARIABLES](https://pastebin.com/yTRV0dGG). I specifically want to know, what are important factors in reducing disk activity and keep more things in caches.

From the previous topic, I would like to increase `Open_tables` but don't know how much to increment (2k to 4k or 2k to 10k) and how to monitor its effect.

I also would like to know if I can collect the number of read and write queries for a period of time. Is that possible?

**UPDATE1:**

Thanks to Rick for the explanation, I used `Open_tables | 4000` and now I see

```
| Uptime                    | 199784 |
| Table_open_cache_misses                 | 210777   |
| Table_open_cache_overflows              | 206768   |
```

So, the miss and overflow rate are now 1.05 and 1.03 which are getting smaller than before and I hope they reach below 1.

On the server, I have installed Moodle and Zabbix. So the following databases are available

```
mysql> show databases;
+--------------------+
| Database           |
+--------------------+
| information_schema |
| moodle             |
| mysql              |
| performance_schema |
| sys                |
| zabbixdb           |
+--------------------+
```

I don't know which database is using `SHOW VARIABLES` and `CREATE INDEX` a lot. But I am curious to see if there is a way to find that. Maybe there is a bug there.

I also used slow query and see few instances that are above 5 seconds from Moodle.

It is explained [here](https://www.interserver.net/tips/kb/mysql-query-caching/) that turning on `query_cache_type` has positive impacts. I have have turned that on. Don't know what are the side effects of that.

I also have increased `max_connections` to 300. Don't know why you said, lower is better in the comments. Did you say that for Apache? That will become a bottleneck then as there are guides to increase the number of connections Apache can handle if the server has resources.

I also have increased `thread_cache_size` to 20. Don't know if I can go further or not. What is expected then?

**UPDATE 2:**

I turned on "general log" for few seconds and a sample for `CREATE INDEX` is shown [here](https://pastebin.com/MQXeEEN5) and the sample for `SHOW VARIABLES` is shown [here](https://pastebin.com/erbnnj0d). So, it seems that Moodle is using those queries a lot.

Comment: How much RAM?  Are other applications running on the same machine?

Comment: System RAM is 32GB with 10 cores..

Comment: 32GB of RAM -- OK.  I analyzed assuming only 16GB.  Perhaps the only edit needed is to suggest increasing `innodb_buffer_pool_size`.

Comment: @RickJames: please see UPDATE 1.

Comment: Turn on the "general log" for a short time.  It will collect _all_ the queries performed, so it fills disk rapidly.

Comment: 5 seconds is rather high for long_query_time; lower it to 1, at least briefly.

Comment: In _some_ systems, the QC is more useful than harmful.  If you do go with it, also use `DEMAND` and add sql_cache or sql_no_cache, as appropriate to each select.

Comment: Having a large number for Apache is like inviting a large number of friends to a party, but not providing masks.  It increases MySQL's risk of being overwhelmed.

Comment: A larger `thread_cache_size` speeds up "connect", but takes some RAM space.  Go ahead and increase it, but not more than max_connections.

Comment: Please see UPDATE 2.

Comment: What the heck?  It creates a temp table (plus indexes), then `SELECTs` without `INSERTing` anything into the table??

Comment: No one repeatedly fetches `max_allowed_packet`.  Moodle is being sloppy.  I wonder if other `VARIABLES` are being repeatedly checked.

Comment: The `SHOW VARIABLES` does not impact disk.  The temp table, plus all its indexes _does_ add to disk activity.  I cannot tell whether the temp table is necessary, or just convenience for the 3rd party package.  If you can work backward to the Moodle code, it _might_ be possible to make things better.

Comment: Thanks for the feedback. I will come back once I got answers about Moodle's architecture.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Observations:**

- Version: 5.7.30-0ubuntu0.18.04.1
- 16 GB of RAM                         -- Is this correct?
- Uptime = 1d 02:44:27
- You are not running on Windows.
- Running 64-bit version
- You appear to be running entirely (or mostly) InnoDB.

**The More Important Issues:**

How many tables do you have?  Apparently `table_open_cache = 2000` is not high enough.  Set it to 4000; then see if `Table_open_cache_overflows / Uptime` and `Table_open_cache_misses / Uptime` drop below 1 per second.

If you are using SSDs, increase `innodb_io_capacity` to 500.

For production servers, it is usally better to turn OFF the Query Cache.

Use the slowlog to discover the "worst" queries.  There seem to be some naughty queries.

Why are you doing `SHOW VARIABLES` twice a second?  And why `CREATE INDEX` a hundred times in a day?

Even in the 26 hours that the server has been up, you have hit `max_connections` (151).  Can you explain why this is happening?  Yes, that setting could be increased, but that could make things worse.  So, we should try to get the root cause.

Increase `thread_cache_size` (from 8) to 20.  (I don't know the optimal number for your server, but apparently 8 is too low.)

**Details and other observations:**

`( Table_open_cache_overflows ) = 135,369 / 96267 = 1.4 /sec`
-- May need to increase table_open_cache (now 2000)

`( Table_open_cache_misses ) = 137,377 / 96267 = 1.4 /sec`
-- May need to increase table_open_cache (now 2000)

`( innodb_lru_scan_depth * innodb_page_cleaners ) = 1,024 * 4 = 4,096` -- Amount of work for page cleaners every second.
-- "InnoDB: page_cleaner: 1000ms intended loop took ..." may be fixable by lowering lru_scan_depth: Consider 1000 / innodb_page_cleaners (now 4). Also check for swapping.

`( innodb_page_cleaners / innodb_buffer_pool_instances ) = 4 / 8 = 0.5` -- innodb_page_cleaners
-- Recommend setting innodb_page_cleaners (now 4) to innodb_buffer_pool_instances (now 8)

`( innodb_lru_scan_depth ) = 1,024`
-- "InnoDB: page_cleaner: 1000ms intended loop took ..." may be fixed by lowering lru_scan_depth

`( innodb_io_capacity_max / innodb_io_capacity ) = 2,000 / 200 = 10` -- Capacity: max/plain
-- Recommend 2. Max should be about equal to the IOPs your I/O subsystem can handle. (If the drive type is unknown 2000/200 may be a reasonable pair.)

`( innodb_flush_method ) = innodb_flush_method =`  -- How InnoDB should ask the OS to write blocks. Suggest O_DIRECT or O_ALL_DIRECT (Percona) to avoid double buffering. (At least for Unix.) See chrischandler for caveat about O_ALL_DIRECT

`( innodb_flush_neighbors ) = 1` -- A minor optimization when writing blocks to disk.
-- Use 0 for SSD drives; 1 for HDD.

`( innodb_io_capacity ) = 200` -- I/O ops per second capable on disk . 100 for slow drives; 200 for spinning drives; 1000-2000 for SSDs; multiply by RAID factor.

`( innodb_print_all_deadlocks ) = innodb_print_all_deadlocks = OFF` -- Whether to log all Deadlocks.
-- If you are plagued with Deadlocks, turn this on. Caution: If you have lots of deadlocks, this may write a lot to disk.

`( character_set_server ) = character_set_server = latin1`
-- Charset problems may be helped by setting character_set_server (now latin1) to utf8mb4. That is the future default.

`( local_infile ) = local_infile = ON`
-- local_infile (now ON) = ON is a potential security issue

`( Qcache_lowmem_prunes ) = 1,739,291 / 96267 = 18 /sec` -- Running out of room in QC
-- increase query_cache_size (now 16777216)

`( Qcache_lowmem_prunes/Qcache_inserts ) = 1,739,291/5746238 = 30.3%` -- Removal Ratio (frequency of needing to prune due to not enough memory)

`( (query_cache_size - Qcache_free_memory) / Qcache_queries_in_cache / query_alloc_block_size ) = (16M - 6135552) / 4715 / 8192 = 0.276` -- query_alloc_block_size vs formula
-- Adjust query_alloc_block_size (now 8192)

`( Created_tmp_disk_tables ) = 226,136 / 96267 = 2.3 /sec` -- Frequency of creating *disk* "temp" tables as part of complex SELECTs
-- increase tmp_table_size (now 16777216) and max_heap_table_size (now 16777216).
Check the rules for temp tables on when MEMORY is used instead of MyISAM. Perhaps minor schema or query changes can avoid MyISAM.
Better indexes and reformulation of queries are more likely to help.

`( Com_show_variables ) = 200,230 / 96267 = 2.1 /sec` -- SHOW VARIABLES ...
-- Why are you requesting the VARIABLES so often?

`( Select_scan ) = 1,067,468 / 96267 = 11 /sec` -- full table scans
-- Add indexes / optimize queries (unless they are tiny tables)

`( Select_scan / Com_select ) = 1,067,468 / 5869892 = 18.2%` -- % of selects doing full table scan. (May be fooled by Stored Routines.)
-- Add indexes / optimize queries

`( slow_query_log ) = slow_query_log = OFF` -- Whether to log slow queries. (5.1.12)

`( long_query_time ) = 10` -- Cutoff (Seconds) for defining a "slow" query.
-- Suggest 2

`( log_slow_slave_statements ) = log_slow_slave_statements = OFF` -- (5.6.11, 5.7.1) By default, replicated statements won't show up in the slowlog; this causes them to show.
-- It can be helpful in the slowlog to see writes that could be interfering with Replica reads.

`( back_log ) = 80` -- (Autosized as of 5.6.6; based on max_connections)
-- Raising to min(150, max_connections (now 151)) may help when doing lots of connections.

`( Max_used_connections / max_connections ) = 152 / 151 = 100.7%` -- Peak % of connections
-- increase max_connections (now 151) and/or decrease wait_timeout (now 28800)

`( Connections ) = 911,023 / 96267 = 9.5 /sec` -- Connections
-- Increase wait_timeout (now 28800); use pooling?

**Abnormally small:**

```
Open_files = 0
```

**Abnormally large:**

```
Com_create_index = 4.2 /HR
Innodb_buffer_pool_pages_misc = 143,234
Innodb_buffer_pool_pages_misc * 16384 / innodb_buffer_pool_size = 27.3%
Innodb_os_log_pending_fsyncs = 1
```

**Abnormal strings:**

```
external_user = root
innodb_fast_shutdown = 1
optimizer_trace = enabled=off,one_line=off
optimizer_trace_features = greedy_search=on, range_optimizer=on, dynamic_range=on, repeated_subselect=on
slave_rows_search_algorithms = TABLE_SCAN,INDEX_SCAN
```

Comment: Excuse me I didn't understand that sentence about running SHOW VARIABLES twice and CREATE INDEX hundreds of time... I haven't set anything for those purposes.

Comment: Regarding `max_connections` I don't know. Are these user connections? The default number of connections in Apache is 150. I guess those look similar. I have increase number of connections in Apache to 700.

Comment: While I see ` Open_tables | 2000`, the output of `SHOW GLOBAL STATUS LIKE 'Opened_tables'` is 201044. Is that normal?

Comment: @mahmood - `CREATE INDEX` is not a common command to run.  Normally it is rarely run after initially building the schema.  However, the STATUS value `Com_create_index` was quite large.  If you were just now creating the schema, then the STATUS is not representative of "normal".  If you do lots of `CREATE INDEXes` every day, we need to discuss "why??".

Comment: @mahmood - Each time a client connects or disconnects, MySQL's `Max_used_connections` is incremented or decremented.  If it hits MySQL's `max_connections`, then the client gets an error like "cannot connect".  150 for Apache is unreasonably high; _lower_ it.

Comment: @mahmood - `Opened_tables` is a counter that keeps going up.  200K/day means that the cache is not big enough.  But the cache is already quite high.  So, I deduce that you have a lot of tables and are jumping around in them a lot?  Partitioning?  Created table names?  Something else?

Comment: @mahmood - In most of your questions (in your Comments), the `STATUS` is saying "something is strange here".  I am turning that into a question to you of "What are you doing?"  After that, we can discuss whether it is a "real problem" and discuss solutions, or "it is a false alarm".